# Rubik's cube Unity 5

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for Android using the Unity 5, the game is the Rubik's cube. I'm not using touch to move the cube, but buttons to make the movement of the cube's rows and columns and for him all rotate got another set of buttons. My problem is this second set of buttons they have to have two functions a rotate the whole cube and another that depends on another button that when precionado it changes the function to u choose the row or column you want to move is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Even if English isn't your first language, code is international. Please try to post what you've done so far. We don't know if you can render your cube, how the objects are organised or how they should be animated.

In short, you will need to complete at least some of the following:

- Render a button on screen using [uGUI Buttons](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button).
- Add a click handler to the button.
- In the click handler, update some variables/model/similar with the new positions.
- Animate the cube to reflect the new positions.
- Either rotate the camera around the cube or rotate the cube and background together.

Unless you provide more information, that's the best answer we can give you.

#### Re Comments:

Have a variable called `locked` that keeps track of if we're locked or not. Have a function to toggle it. Wire the "Locked" button up to `ToggleLocked`...

```
private bool locked = false;

public void ToggleLocked() {
    locked = !locked;
}
```

And then in your button methods, check if we're locked before doing anything...

```
public void SomeButtonClicked() {
    //check if we're locked
    if(!locked) {
        //If not, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try explain better: I made two groups of buttons with the four directions. One of this groups, control the faces of Rubik and the second group move the the rows and columns. But, I need to do a button that will change the function of the first group. My idea is make a button called "locked". When this button is pressed, the first group of buttons will not to move the faces. They will select the rows and columns of the Rubik. I already have the Rubik's interface and buttons too. But I can't make the second function of buttons work after the button "locked" is pressed.

Comment: See if that helps at all?